# Oracle SQL Interpolation

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, interpolation

I am having trouble solving a problem of linear interpolation with Oracle SQL.
I start with data like the one in the following table:

```
 Bucket        My Value
  1         22,506,791,194.47 
  7         12,506,791,194.47 
  15        2,506,791,194.47 
  30        1,605,711,104.47 
  90       -3,128,740,962.21
```

Where the Bucket is in days. The whole point is that I need to find the exact day (using interpolation) when My Value will turn negative , I know it is at some point betweeen 30 and 90 days if I interpolate.

I saw another example here [How can I perform linear interpolation using oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366308/how-can-i-perform-linear-interpolation-using-oracle-sql)

But it is not the same since I need to find a particular value (The 0)

Thanks

Comment: What is the algorithm that you want to implement?  Do you just want to calculate a linear least squares line that best fits the data and to determine where that approximation has a value of 0?

Comment: That's it a simple linear OLS would work, though I prefer to interpolate. The point is to get as close as posible to the day the data passes the x axis. Assuming x as the days

Comment: There are multiple possible interpolation algorithms.  I would expect that a least squares line fit would produce a more accurate result than doing a simple estimate from the point just above 0 and the point just below 0.  I would expect that the other data points would add some information.  But that is a guess, I don't know your data.  You presumably do.  Gordon's answer appears correct if you want to ignore all but two points.

Answer (score 2):

It would be something like this:

```
select (abs(prev_value) / (value - prev_value)) * (bucket - prev_bucket) + prev_bucket
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by bucket) as prev_value,
             lag(bucket) over (order by bucket) as prev_bucket
      from t
     ) t
where prev_value < 0 and value > 0;
```